# Error attaching existing database entity framework code first

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have created an application using Entity Framework 6 code-first, in ASP.NET MVC 5, and am bin deploying it to my server. Everything works fine, except for the operations/controller actions that involve database usage.

I am uploading the once-generated database file from my computer to the `App_Data` folder of the server.

Upon deploying, I changed the connection string in my web.config file from:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-NERC_Main-20160104065223.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-NERC_Main-20160104065223;Integrated Security=True"
```

to

```
connectionString="Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-NERC_Main-20160104065223.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-NERC_Main-20160104065223;Database=aspnet-NERC_Main-20160104065223.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=True;"
```

which throws an error of

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

A probable cause of this is because the present database file is not being attached, and the entity framework is trying to generate a new database in some other, restricted directory.

I read that the `AttachDbFileName` is valid for SQL Server Express instances only, which in my case doesn't exist.

How can I modify the connection string so that my current, already uploaded database is utilized.

**Note:**

The remote server has a full installation of SQL Server 2008 R2. The server does not support user instances. My database is not password protected, and hence I've set the Integrated Security property value to True. I'll provide any other information if required.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a full version of SQL Server, you cannot just use `AttachDbFileName`. Instead, you need to copy the `.mdf` (and `.ldf`) to the SQL Server data file location and then you need to **attach** the database in SQL Server Management Studio to the server instance.

From that point on, you can reference that database in your connection string using the server name, and the logical database name - something like this:

```
Server=.;Database=aspnet-NERC_Main-20160104065223;Integrated Security=True;
```

Depending on your database setup, you may or may not be able to use the `Integrated Security` - maybe you'll need to have a specific SQL Server login and specify that login (and its password) in your connection string instead:

```
Server=.;Database=aspnet-NERC_Main-20160104065223;User ID=YourUserName;Password=YourPassword
```

See [this site here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for a ton of sample of how to build valid connection strings for SQL Server.

Comment: So, there is absolutely no way I could directly attach it (or in my case, use the existing files from App_Data folder) without consulting the Server Administrator to do the task of attaching database to the server for me?

Comment: @AbdullahGulraiz: no. The "attach a free-floating `.mdf` file from `App_Data`" works **exclusively** with the Express edition